# size of figure in sns.histplot

Tags: python, histplot

I was trying to fix the size of figure when comparing one variable to other.

```
columns = ['Education_Level' ]
bins = [30, 6]
for i, columns in enumerate(columns): 
  #plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
    fig = sns.FacetGrid(BankChurners, col='Attrition_Flag', hue='Attrition_Flag', height=5)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
    fig.map(sns.histplot, columns, bins=bins[i], kde=False)
```

[image]

as you can see below that the labels don't appear clearly. I have tried figzie(15,8) and other things but no luck. If you have a hint or idea that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have specified the `height` in the `FacetGrid` function. Now try using the `aspect` parameter to control the ratio between height and width, *e.g.*:

```
fig = sns.FacetGrid(BankChurners, col='Attrition_Flag', hue='Attrition_Flag', height=5, aspect=0.35)
```

You will find a few example plots in the `FacetGrid` [help page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).

Comment: thanks it works. I change the aspect = 1.40